# How to add custom Bootstrap themes to Heroku?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, heroku, npm, themes

I'm very much a noob and building my 1st Node-Angular application. I've installed Bootstrap using npm and downloaded a custom theme from https://bootswatch.com/, which suggests replacing the default bootstrap.css file with the theme css file.

This works well when the app is being run locally, but how can I get the theme to work in Heroku? Heroku runs npm install every time I do a git push and therefore overwrites the custom css theme in the node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/ directory.

What would be the best approach to use a Bootstrap theme in Heroku when bootstrap is installed via npm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the downloaded bootswatch css file somewhere in your main project directory, not in `node_modules/` (you may want to create a `vendor/` folder to keep it separate from you other code).

Change your code to reference the bootswatch css file instead of the css in `node_modules/`. You can reference the bootstrap JS from `node_modules/` as usual.

In general, you should never modify files in `node_modules/`, since they will be overwritten with reinstalls.